# Non-interactive "git clean -fdx"

Tags: windows, git

I'm building a thing that processes incoming file packages, but I have the rather serious problem that I can't sanitize the incoming data until it's in a position to break the processing, and it breaks it such a way that simply restarting the process doesn't fix it.

My current best solution is to `git clean -fdx` and `git checkout .` the project directory the process uses, which works like a charm, *except* that sometimes `git clean` asks for user input ("cannot unlink file. Retry?"), which causes a problem for automation.

Is there a way to put Git into a non-interactive mode? I need to do this from inside Ruby on a Windows machine.

Comment: Why do you modify the local copy at first?

Comment: I don't know how to do that with git alone. Since you are using ruby, maybe write a `y\n` with `open3` ?

Comment: That's the current plan, but I'm hoping for a better way.

Comment: @zerkms: Consequence of the third-party process, nothing I can do about it :/

Answer (score 9):

For Windows, this is what worked for me (sets the GIT_ASK_YESNO environment variable to false, stopping git from asking yes-no questions):

```
set GIT_ASK_YESNO=false
```

Then when I get those same messages as warnings but it continues as if I said no.

So `git clean -fdx` works for me as expected without blocking.

Answer (score 2):

```
yes no | git clean -fdx
```

`yes no` outputs `no` forever and piping that into `git clean` causes every prompt to be answered with `no`.

Answer (score 0):

This generally is because of other processes keeping an handle to those files which "cannot be unliked" (as mentioned in "[Cannot unlink a file in PHP/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15475942/6309)").

That means your automated job has to make sure that all running processes are stopped/killed first, before updating the working directory.

Comment: I also don't mind keeping the files that cannot be unlinked, as they're not the ones that break my process, and the process that's using them is already supposedly stopped at this point. Is there a way to tell Git to just let those be, and not as the user on a file-by-file basis?

Comment: @Narfanator Not that I know of, as it is more a Linux error, not a git error.

Comment: I'm on Windows, although I don't expect that to help.

Comment: @Narfanator yes, I meant it is an OS error, not a tool (git) error.

Comment: One would think the -f trigger should tell it to continue and not stop and block on every single file like almost every other tool ever, or maybe even the -q to make it quiet like virtually EVERY other tool. 

Its sort of strange that neither force or quiet seems to behave like one might expect.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I don't know Ruby.

Per the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean), and short of coding up a way to kill all the services that are still running (which may be the best route, depending on your solution and what you need to clean in order to test it) the best it seems we can hope for with this command is to make a shortlist of the files that always result in a `[Y/n]` prompt.

So, when I see the following:

> Unlink of file 'packages/RavenDB.Server.2.5.2851/tools/blahblahblah failed.

I add the following to my command:

```
git clean -fdx --exclude=/packages/RavenDB.Server.2.5.2851**
```

And, it seems to work.