# how to auto skip "Unlink of file Failed", when i run "git gc"

Tags: git, garbage-collection, unlink

When i run "git gc", sometimes things go wrong.

```
Unlink of file '*******.pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

I know I can skip it by typing "n".
My question is: how to auto skip it, whitout any input.

Comment: Maybe try setting the `GIT_ASK_YESNO` environment variable to `false` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071604/3486675).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @X Deming, I posted it as an answer now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `GIT_ASK_YESNO` environment variable to `false`. It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but it seems to not ask for input anymore (and thereby assuming you don't want it to try again).

I got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629650/non-interactive-git-clean-fdx/53071604#53071604) and see it's being used in the git source [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8679ef24ed64018bb62170c43ce73e0261c0600a/compat/mingw.c#L189).